# Getting 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException' while performing GraphRequest.executeAndWait() in doInBackground() of AsyncTask

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk, networkonmainthread

I'm using Facebook GraphAPI and I'm trying to load results from next page using `GraphRequest.executeAndWait()` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36495533/6144372), but the app is crashing giving `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Here's my code:

```
    class RetrieveF extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

            GraphRequest request;

            protected String doInBackground(Void...args0) {
                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                JSONObject innerJson = response.getJSONObject();
                                try {
                                    JSONArray data = innerJson.getJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i<data.length(); i++){

                                        String id = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                                        request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), id+"/feed", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                                        JSONObject innerJson = response.getJSONObject();
                                                        try {
                                                            JSONArray data = innerJson.getJSONArray("data");
                                                            for (int i = 0; i<data.length(); i++) {
                                                                JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);}
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            Log.d("innerFacebookException", e.getMessage());
                                                        }

                                                        GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                                                        if (nextResultsRequests != null) {
                                                            nextResultsRequests.setCallback(request.getCallback());
                                                            // error on this line
                                                            response = nextResultsRequests.executeAndWait();
                                                            //
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        );
                                        request.executeAsync();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.d("facebookException", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
            }
        }
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
                                                                       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1126)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.Connection.closeIfOwnedBy(Connection.java:132)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.closeIfOwnedBy(OkHttpClient.java:75)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.closeIfOwnedBy(HttpConnection.java:137)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.disconnect(HttpTransport.java:135)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.disconnect(HttpEngine.java:578)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:122)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.disconnect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:93)
                                                                       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                                                       at com.facebook.internal.Utility.disconnectQuietly(Utility.java:416)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeConnectionAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1272)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1168)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1134)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1118)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1093)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:987)
                                                                       at com.qbc.xxx.MainActivity$RetrieveFacebookPosts$1$1.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:398)
                                                                       at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1383)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm unable to figure out what's causing this error as such errors are usually caused when this sort of code is not handled in `AsyncTask` but that is not the case here.

Please let me know what's causing this error and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace, too.

Comment: @laalto please see the updated question

Comment: The innermost `onCompleted()` callback is running on the main thread, and you're performing an `executeAndWait()` there.

Comment: @MikeM. how is it on main thread and what can be done here?

Comment: You probably have to use another `AsyncTask` for the second request

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez So can I execute this second `AsyncTask` in first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few google searches I got the solution.

I just wrapped the `GraphRequest.executeAndWait()` code in a `Thread` like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = lastGraphResponse.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
        if (nextResultsRequests != null) {
            nextResultsRequests.setCallback(request.getCallback());
            lastGraphResponse = nextResultsRequests.executeAndWait();
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

`public void onCompleted()` is run on the UI thread regardless of which thread called this request. So if you want to perform another request inside `public void onCompleted()`, you will have to wrap it into another `AsyncTask`, or other async mechanism.

Comment: Ok! So, if I'd write another `AsyncTask`. I'd have to pass `request` as parameters. How can I do that with AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right approach

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = lastGraphResponse.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    if (nextResultsRequests != null) {
        nextResultsRequests.setCallback(request.getCallback());
        lastGraphResponse = nextResultsRequests.executeAndWait();
    }
}
```

}.start();

You are doing that by creating a new thread. All network operations should be done in the **background** thread which already exists, not by creating a new thread.

The way to do this is using a **handler** object to run the code on **main thread**.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = lastGraphResponse.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
            if (nextResultsRequests != null) {
                nextResultsRequests.setCallback(request.getCallback());
                lastGraphResponse = nextResultsRequests.executeAndWait();
            }
        }
    });
```

Or you can do the operation after some delay, by using **postDelayed**

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = lastGraphResponse.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
            if (nextResultsRequests != null) {
                nextResultsRequests.setCallback(request.getCallback());
                lastGraphResponse = nextResultsRequests.executeAndWait();
            }
        }
    }, DELAY_IN MILLISECONDS);
```